# JasperReports in zkoss can't find .jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports, zk

I'm using *ZK 6.0.1* and *JasperReports 4.1.1*

I getting this bad result

```
HTTP Status 410 - /view/z_b72/eMvPx1/gvv/0/D:/wrk/.html - <Jasperreport eMvPx1> not found.

type Status report

message /view/z_b72/eMvPx1/gvv/0/D:/wrk/.html - <Jasperreport eMvPx1> not found.

description The requested resource is no longer available, and no forwarding address is known.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
```

I think seems that it can't find your .jasper file

and this is my java code :

```
String path=Sessions.getCurrent().getWebApp().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/report/cobaReport.jasper");
Jasperreport rpt=new Jasperreport();
List<AccountGroup> accountGroups;
accountGroups = masterCoaManager.findAllAccg();
Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("terranTitle", "Hoax");
parameters.put("terranDataSource", new AccountGroupDataSource(accountGroups));

rpt.setSrc(path);
rpt.setParameters(parameters);
rpt.setType("html");
divReport.appendChild(rpt);
```

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

See [Integration OF Jasper Report in ZK Web application](http://zkframeworkhint.blogspot.in/2012/10/integrate-dyanmic-jasper-reprot-with-zk.html)